# Allow only space, underscore , alphabets and numbers in text box

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code which allows all characters in a text box. It allows only alphabets and numbers as first character. Now, how do I allow only space and underscore along with alphabets and numbers? I want code only in jQuery. I found a similar solution over here but it doesn't contain jQuery code. http://jsfiddle.net/fwcfq/39/

```
    $('#value').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if($('#value').val().length == 0){
            if (e.which == 32){//space bar
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which     <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
            if (!valid) {
               e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: spaces and underscores for the first letter? or do you want all the letters to be numbers/letters or spaces/underscores

Comment: First character should be alphabet or number. Second character can be alphabet/number/space/underscore.

Comment: shouldn't that be var valid  = `expr && expr && expr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you want

```
$('#value').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if ($('#value').val().length == 0) {
        if (e.which == 32) { //space bar
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122);
        if (!valid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        var valid = (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122 || e.which == 32 || e.which == 95 || e.which == 8);
        if (!valid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwcfq/49/)

This approach assumes you know all keys that you want to accept however. For instance the Enter key will be rejected unless you explicitly allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use one of many jQuery plugins doing the same.
Example: http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input

regex would be: [a-zA-Z _]